# Master routing page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Former I had created my own MVC and there was an `index.php` that all pages passed from the way of it. I mean, I could put a redirect (`header('Location: ..');`) into `index.php`, and then none of my website pages can not be opened.

Now I use Laravel and I need a core-page (like `index.php`). Because my new website supports multi-languages. Here is my current code:

```
// app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('/{locale?}', 'HomeController@index');


// app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
public function index($locale = null)
{
    if(!is_null($locale)) {
        Lang::setLocale($locale);
    }

    dd(Lang::getLocale());
    /* http://localhost:8000        => output: en   -- default
     * http://localhost:8000/abcde  => output: en   -- fallback language
     * http://localhost:8000/en     => output: en   -- defined language
     * http://localhost:8000/es     => output: es   -- defined language
     * http://localhost:8000/fa     => output: fa   -- defined language
     */
}
```

As you see, in my current algorithm, I need to check the language that the user has set for each route. Also my website has almost 30 routes. I can do that manually 30 times for each route, but I think there is a way which lets me to do that once for all routes. Isn't there?

In other word, how can I set current language *(the user has set)* for each page? Should I check/set it for each route separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a smarter way in Laravel for solve your trouble. It is called [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware). So you can just create LangMiddleware and put your logic inside.

Something like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $locale = null)
{
    if ($locale && in_array($locale, config('app.allowed_locales'))) {
        Lang::setLocale($locale);
    }
    else{
        Lang::setLocale(config('app.fallback_locale'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with `Middleware`, but I don't know how should I implement it. thanks anyway, upvote

Comment: @MartinAJ Please check updated answer. It's just idea, you'll need fix any bug in my implementation:)